# Stop SageMaker endpoint

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

I use the update_endpoint method of the boto3 SageMaker client.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('sagemaker')

endpoint_name = 'my-endpoint'
desired_status = 'OutOfService'

response = client.update_endpoint(
    EndpointName=endpoint_name,
    DesiredStatus=desired_status
)

print(response)
```

`Response { "errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': cannot assign to operator (lambda_function.py, line 6)",`

I’m seeking a way to schedule the starting and stopping of SageMaker Endpoint.
Please help me is there is any way to set desire count zero or stop endpoint?

Comment: Are you sure that this is exactly the code you are running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sharing my experience with creating code to manage SageMaker endpoints.  I scheduled the starting and deleting of the endpoint using AWS Lambda with event scheduler trigger.

Below is python script that automates the creation and deletion of SageMaker endpoints using the Boto3 library for AWS.

**Script for Endpoint Creation:**

```
import boto3
endpoint_config_name = "your_endpoint_config_name"
sagemaker = boto3.client("sagemaker")
endpoint_name = "endpoint-with-same-name"
sagemaker.create_endpoint(
  EndpointName=endpoint_name,
  EndpointConfigName=endpoint_config_name
)
```

**Script for Endpoint Deletion:**

```
import boto3
endpoint_name = "endpoint-with-same-name"
sagemaker_client = boto3.client('sagemaker')
sagemaker_client.delete_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name)
```

I successfully implemented EventBridge schedulers to automate the start and delete processes for SageMaker endpoint. However, I observed that the creation of SageMaker endpoints takes approximately 7 to 10 minutes.

**Thank you all**

Answer (score 1):

First off - I don't understand how the code you posted should work. There is no `desired_status` parameter in the `update_endpoint()` method.

To actually solve your problem, I'd suggest using `EventBridge` Schedulers. Use one scheduler targeting the `sagemaker:createEndpoint` method, and one scheduler targeting the `sagemaker:deleteEndpoint` method.

As both creating and invoking a `SageMaker` endpoint is done via its name, it is perfectly fine to completely delete it in case it is not required temporarily. You should be able to recreate it without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at SageMaker Async endpoints/ Serverless Endpoints. In case of Async endpoints, with the appropriate AutoScaling policy you can reduce the number of instances to zero when there is no traffic and hence avoid being charged.

In Serverless Endpoints, you don't need to provision instances behind the endpoint, they are automatically scaled and teared down like a Lambda function.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/async-inference.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/serverless-endpoints.html